# A function is outside main,it requires use of a variable how do use it?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

My function is outside main()

it's this

```
void Ydisplay(int D1[])
{
 for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
  {
   cout<<"\t<<D1[i];
}
```

the array D1 is a dynamic array
the error is 'a' is undefined it's taken from user so it has to be in main..
but is there any other option?

Comment: FYI, you don't have to take user input from `main`, it can be anywhere. Also, you can pass `a` to the function as an argument, much like you did with `D1`.

Comment: Could you please write a piece of code as I am not able to take inputs from user outside the main..the compiler is assuming cout to be a variable..Thank you.

Comment: `cout` is a variable.

Comment: @DeepKanakia: No, we do not write code for you. You have to do that yourself. Programming takes effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a` is not know to function Ydisplay() it is local to main(), Pass value `a` from main.

change function syntax as:

```
void Ydisplay(int D1[], int a)
                         ^ add
```

A syntax error,  missing `"`:

```
cout<<"\t" <<D1[i];
     //  ^  added
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Your link don't open to me :) , pulse I disagree here with you because I have explained what is the mistake, for what reason and then I answered how to rectify. I didn't post correct answer. And because it exactly answer to question I posted an answer not comment. Yes I understand that question is very poor (doesn't meet standard) at stackoverflow. For this one may wish to down vote Question.  Am I wrong **?**

Comment: Yeah, you didn't though. By answering this poor question you only encourage the OP and others to post further poor questions in the future.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes then I agree with you, I will take care and will not feed the vampires from next time :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the array size along as a function parameter:

```
void Ydisplay(std::size_t len, int D1[])
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != len ;++i)
    {
        std::cout << '\t' << D1[i];
    }
}
```

In C++, you would use a `std:vector<int>`, though.

```
void Ydisplay(std::vector<int> const & D1)
{
    for (int n : D1)
    {
        std::cout << '\t' << n;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your function in this way.,

```
void Ydisplay(int D1[])
{
 cin >> a; //Remove getting input from main()
 for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
  {
   cout<<'\t'<<D1[i];
}
```

Comment: Well this does work! the problem now is a is my array size too.Then the 'a' outside the function remains undefined.thanks if you could help

Comment: ya in that case, you could use ,  `void Ydisplay(std::size_t len, int D1[])` or `void Ydisplay(std::vector<int> const & D1)` as Kerrek SB said. And moreover Cout is a object of class `Ostream` Ask Google. you will find. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to understand what you are trying to do. In this particular code, You are trying to print elements that are in the array D1. So you print the element starting from D1[0] to D1[n]. You use the for loop to traverse through each element in the array D1. int i starts at i = 0 to the last element which is i < sizeof(D1)/sizeof(int). You don`t need variable a, it make no sense with what you are trying to do. To print on each line try: cout << D1[i] << endl;